# C# using Linq form and lambda form : how to find all the multiple of x in an array of numbers

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to create a Linq query and a linq lambda form which would return all the numbers of an array which would be a multiple of x and y. Let’s say 4 and 6. The array would look like this: int[] multiple = (3, 6,, 8, 12, 16, 18, 19, 24, 26);

The actual answer, the linq query, would return: 6, 12, 16, 18, 24 since they all are multiple of 4 and 6 (x and y). In short all numbers who don’t equal to zero can be removed or vice versa… Something like that. It would be nice to get both forms.

I am a newbie so all I have yet :

```
int[] numbers = { 3, 6, 8, 12, 16, 18, 19, 24, 26 };

int[] multipleOf = number.Where((x) => multiple.All((y) => y % x == 0)).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm a little confused: do you mean "x **and** y" or "x **or** y"? You say both and your example "actual answer" matches "x or y" but your code matches "x and y" (if I  ignore the syntax error `numbers != number`)

Comment: Also, please explain how your current attempt does not live up to your expectation and what the difference between "Classic linq" and "lambda" is

Comment: I think the OP means method syntax vs query syntax

Comment: I did mean both &&. It was a bit confusing. I did remove the or between x and y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean are multiples of "both x and y" or "either x and y", however:

```
int x = 4;
int y = 6;

int[] test = new int[] { 3, 6, 8, 12, 16, 18, 19, 24, 26 };

var test2 = test.Where(i => i % x == 0 || i % y == 0).ToList();

var test3 = (from integer in test
             where integer % x == 0 || integer % y == 0
             select integer).ToList();
```

Replace "||" in the lambda query with "&&" if it should be both rather than either.
I have included ToList() as you appear to be looking for a list, but you could use ToArray() or consume the enumerable another way.

Comment: Ok I'll work on my coding using this example. Thanks.